# find() not working properly. Cant find span

Tags: jquery, html

Trying to fill a span by finding it and using innterHTML but for some reason it doesn't do anything. No error, no succes, doesnt print anything. What has gone wrong?

```
<label class="myClass" data-id="1"><input type="checkbox" name="group" value="my_value">my value<span class="left" ></span></label>andmoreandmore
```

I've put it in a for loop for getting the classes

```
var element = $('.myClass')[i];

var numberThing = 50 - count;
$(element).find("span").innerHTML = numberThing + ' plekken vrij';
```

Comment: juse use `element.find("span").innerHTML = numberThing + ' plekken vrij';` no need to `$` since you have `var element = $('.myClass').eq(i);` also check the initialization as well..i dont know where is cimong from but if you use `.eq()` it starts at 0

Comment: `innerHTML` is DOM node property, not jq object one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well what has gone wrong is that you did not select the correct span, or better said.. none at all

You need to select `span[0]` because you are selecting a DOM element the wrong way.

```
var element = $('.myClass')[i];
var numberThing = 50 - count;
$(element).find("span")[0].innerHTML = numberThing + ' plekken vrij';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `html()` instead of innerHTML

```js
var element = $('.myClass');
var count = 3;
                var numberThing = 50 - count;
                $(element).find("span").html(numberThing + ' plekken vrij');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <label class="myClass" data-id="1"><input type="checkbox" name="group" value="my_value">my value<span class="left" ></span></label>andmoreandmore
```

Replace

```
var element = $('.myClass')[i]
```

with

```
var element  = $('.myClass').eq(i);
```

Comment: does html() and innerHTML make a difference?

Comment: since you are using jquery and $(element) thus you should using html() ie jquery equivalent of innerHTML

Comment: But does it make a big difference, because both work?

Comment: No it doesn't. I tried innerHTML but it did not work, so suggested to use html() that always works for me

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.eq()` instead of `[]`. Because $('.myClass')[i] will return a dom element. which means for using the jquery methods, you need to wrap it with `$()` again. Instead of these, you can use,

```
$('.myClass').eq(i).find("span").html(numberThing + ' plekken vrij');
```